# How do I graph this limit?

Tags: limits, graphing-functions

How do I graph this limit ? The function has a limit as $x$ approaches $2$ of $5$ but $f(2) =4$. Specifically, what does $2$ of $5$ mean? The problem also wants me to write piecewise equations.

Comment: "The function has a limit as $x$ approaches 2 of 5" might be better written as "The function has a limit -- as $x$ approaches 2 -- of 5" or "The function has a limit of 5, as $x$ approaches 2" and this means $$\lim_{x\to 2}f(x)=5$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your graph, whatever the function is will approach a $y$ value of 5 from both left and right sides but you will draw a point at the location $(2,4)$.  The nomenclature you are using looks like this..

"The limit as x approaches 2 of $f(x)$ is 5" can also be written "the limit of $f(x)$ as x approaches 2 is 5" and is notationally written as
$$\lim_{x\to2}f(x)=5$$

Comment: You're reading things wrongly. The OP is writing that $$\lim_{x\to 2}f(x)=5$$

Comment: Thanks @petertamaroff.  Yes I did read it wrong .  I edited it.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is discontinuous at $x=2$. The graph would look like [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aDiscontinuity_removable.eps.png) in the sense that it will have a line, described by your function, which approaches a y-value of 5 in the neighborhood of $x=2$ but there will be a hole at $(2,5)$ and a lone point at $(2,4)$.

For a piecewise equation, you need to write the function as

$f(x) = \left\{
   \begin{array}{lr}
    \text{your_function} & : x \neq 2\\
    4 & : x=2
    \end{array}
   \right.$